# Poweshell popping up

Tags: powershell

I tried installing a cracked app, tried patching it, nothing worked, so I just deleted it and ignored it, after a reboot, i got this message, went in the files and deleted it, error was gone [image: script host error]
BUT
powershell was popping up [image: powershell error message]

Text of the error message:

```
Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly '1769248 bytes loaded from Anonymously
Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An
attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."
At line:1 char:91
+ ... se($bytes); [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($bytes).EntryPoint.Inv ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadImageFormatException
```

and closing it doesn't work it pops up soon after.

Restarting it does't work, registry fixing now working, disk clean up, sfc scan clean.
Malware clean.

Comment: Something probably still runs automatically when you log in. You can use [`autoruns.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to inspect what runs automatically on system startup and on user login, and remove unwanted entries.

Comment: From the file path in the error, it sounds like it may have put a file here:

%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Start-up

any files in there are executed when you login. The Powershell Windows Event log can also show you the path of the file that was run which opened that powershell as well, if it was a file.

Personally though I would reset Windows, as you have no idea what else that crack did, it could have installed all sorts on your computer, without you knowing. Windows Sandbox, or Oracle VirtualBox VM is a better way to go if you are running stuff like that.